# Set logged user in another entity with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to set the logged user in a set method for another entity. For example, I have the entities Article and User (User is an FOSUser entity). I want to set the current user as author for an article.

In the Article entity, I write:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="articles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
  protected $user;

   /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setUser(\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        //This line is the problem
        $this->user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        return $this;
    }
```

I'm trying to get the user from the container, but when I perform a save, the set value is null. I test the line in a controller and I get successfully the current user. Maybe inside an entity the method for get the logged user is different?

Comment: The given answers work in a Controller. You can also set this in a Doctrine Lifecycle Event and have it done automatically instead of having to set it manually.

Answer (score 1):

An Entity cannot access the service container, also you cannot use any service inside.

To make it working, call the `Article::setUser()` from a controller or another context that can use the `container`. e.g. :

```
$currentUser = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

$article = new Article();
$article->setUser($currentUser);
// ...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

And the field will be correctly filled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the user with the function chalasr said

```
$article->setUser($this->getUser());
```

persist it to db and you are done :)